# SSIS Script Task not displaying Variable Value

Tags: ssis

I have created a variable in my SSIS Package and assigned a value to it.

```
my variable name is "myvariable" which is assigned some value at the time of creation.
```

I want to show this value in my Script Task using messagebox.show option as below.

```
String myval = "";
myval=Dts.Variables["User::myvariable"].Value.ToString();
MessageBox.Show(myval);
```

But While displaying the message it showing blank.

But if I do the below code instead of the above code It is showing the value.

```
String myval = "";
Dts.Variables["User::myvariable"].Value = "MYVALUE";
myval=Dts.Variables["User::myvariable"].Value.ToString();
MessageBox.Show(myval);
```

Please Advise.

Comment: Have you specified this variable as *ReadVariable* in Script Task properties?

Comment: I tried both with readvariable and readwritevariable also. Still it is not working

Comment: Are you sure you are properly setting myvariable to equal something in the package?

Comment: Anyway, put a break point on the first line of your code and step through (F11) looking at locals